# Is write/fwrite guaranteed to be sequential?

Tags: c, posix, libc

Is the data written via `write` (or `fwrite`) guaranteed to be persisted to the disk in a sequence manner?  In particular in relation to fault tolerance. If the system should fail during the write, will it behave as though first bytes were written first and writing stopped mid-stream (as opposed to random blocks written).

Also, are sequential calls to `write`/`fwrite` guaranteed to be sequential? According to POSIX I find only that a call to `read` is guaranteed to consider a previous `write`.

I'm asking as I'm creating a fault tolerant data store that persists to disks. My logical order of writing is such that faults won't ruin the data, but if the logical order isn't being obeyed I have a problem.

*Note: I'm not asking if persistence is guaranteed. Only that if my calls to write do eventually persist they obey the order in which I actually write.*

Comment: Would you mind defining "*fail*"  more detailed? `EIO`, or what else?

Comment: @alk Any failures, program aborts abruptly, power off, freeze. Just anything that prevents flushing pending disk writes to disk.

Comment: I don't think there is any such guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

[The POSIX docs for `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) state that "If the O_DSYNC bit has been set, write I/O operations on the file descriptor shall complete as defined by synchronized I/O data integrity completion". Presumably, if the `O_DSYNC` bit isn't set, then the synchronization of I/O data integrity completion is unspecified.  POSIX also says that "This volume of POSIX.1-2008 is also silent about any effects of application-level caching (such as that done by stdio)", so I think there is no guarantee for `fwrite()`.

Comment: I looked but I can't find a definition of "synchronized I/O data integrity", other than saying it is synchronously written.  Synchronous write actually isn't what I want really, I just want a guaranteed write order (I don't care if it actually writes everything).

Comment: Short story short, dsync semantics have nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert, but I might know enough to point you in the right direction:

The most disastrous case is if you lose power, so that is the only one worth considering.

- Start with a file with X bytes of meaningful content, and a header that indicates it.
- Write Y bytes of meaningful content somewhere that won't invalidate X.
- Call `fsync` (slow!).
- Update the header (probably has to be less than your disk's block size).

I don't know if changing the length of a file is safe. I don't know how much depends on the filesystem mount mode, except that any "safe" mode is probably completely unusable for systems need to have even a slight level of performance.

Keep in mind that on some systems the `fsync` call lies and just returns without doing anything safely. You can tell because it returns quickly. For this reason, you need to make pretty large transactions (i.e. much larger than application-level transactions).

Keep in mind that the kind of people who solve this problem in the real world get paid high 6 figures at least. The best answer for the rest of us is either "just send the data to postgres and let it deal with it." or "accept that we might have to lose data and revert to an hourly backup."

Comment: I'm looking for a soltuion where I don't have to rely on `fsync`.  I don't need the writes to be synchronous, just some kind of order guarantee (which sounds like it may not be possible).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y you might try `man ext4` or whatever your filesystem is and look at options such as `data=ordered` and `auto_da_alloc`. Beware that whatever the man page calls the "default" might not be what you are actually using on your system, even if you don't have any options in `fstab`.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Fsync there is not to make writes synchronous but acts as a barrier before updating header. Header should be exactly 512 bytes because of atomic sector writes.

Comment: Fsync used to lie in the past, or call it "changed semantics". It used to be that fsync only pushed from memory buffer to disk. If disk was also buffering writes then you had no safety anyway. New kernels properly push disk buffers to platter. Look into `man fsync`.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general as far as POSIX and reality are concerned, filesystems do not provide such guarantee. Order of persistence (in which disk makes them permanent on the platter) is not dictated by order in which syscalls were made, or position within the file, or order of sectors on disk. Filesystems retain the data to be written in memory for several seconds, hoarding as much as possible, and later send them to disk in batches, in whatever order they seem fit. And regardless of how kernel sends it to disk, the disk itself can reorder writes on its own due to NCQ.

Filesystems have means of ensuring *some* ordering for safety. Barriers were used in the past, and explicit flushes and FUA requests nowadays. There is a good [article on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/400541/) about that. But those are used by filesystems, not applications.

I strongly suggest reading the article about [Application Level Consistency](https://www.academia.edu/9846821/Towards_Efficient_Portable_Application-Level_Consistency). Not sure how relevant to you but it shows many behaviors that developers wrongly assumed in the past.

Answer from o11c is a good way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, so long as we are not talking about adding in the complexity of multithreading.  It will be in the same order on disk, for what makes it to disk.  It buffers to memory and dumps that memory to disk when it fills up, or you close the file.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a standard or help page that indicates this guarantee?

Comment: Neither order of persistence nor layout on disk is guaranteed in general.

Comment: the OP wasnt asking about layout on disk, just order of the data that he'd get when doing a read.